# Linear algebra proof - transpose and square

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that if the squared matrix $AA^T = A$ then $A^2 = A$.

I have played around with transpose rules and gotten to things like
$(A^TA)^T = A^T$ and $(A^2)^T = A^T \Rightarrow (A^T)^2 = A^T$ and have set $AA^T = A^2$.

With matrices,  $AB = AC$ does not always translate to $B = C$, so I guess that $AA^T = A \Rightarrow AA^T = AI \Rightarrow A^T = I $ is not the way to go...

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A = AA^T$ implies $A^T = (AA^T)^T = A^{TT}A^T = AA^T = A$ and so $A = AA^T = AA = A^2$.

Comment: .interesting. We see that $A$ is here symmetrical and projection matrix. The same probably would be obtained from $A^TA=A$...